# Fitting static sized website to mobile browser

Tags: html, css, meta-tags

I have a mainwrapper div container with a fixed width of 900px.  How can I scale this wrapper so  it is entirely visible on load in a mobile browser with width approx 300px.  I don't want to have to change the 900px, I'm hoping there is a way to do this with the meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

There is. Use:

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=900">`

If you want to prevent zooming entirely, use this instead:

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=900, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: I tried this but the mobile browser still isn't fully zoomed out to show the full 900 px wrapper on load.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I've tested that code on iPhones and Androids and it works. You may want to create a minimum viable test out of your app (just make a page that's a 900px wide box with a border and see if it's in the right place with that meta tag). If that works (it does) but your app doesn't, then your app is doing something else to break it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code, working fine with all browser except Opera Android Browser. In Opera my site floating, but width is wrapped.

```
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no' name='viewport'/>
```